# Perl In place edit: Find and replace in X12850 formatted file

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl and cannot figure this out. I have a file called **Test**:

```
ISA^00^          ^00^          ^01^SupplyScan     ^01^NOVA           ^180815^0719^U^00204^000000255^0^P^^
GS^PO^SupplyScan^NOVA^20180815^0719^00000255^X^002004
ST^850^00000255
BEG^00^SA^0000000059^^20180815
DTM^097^20180815^0719
N1^BY^^92^
N1^SE^^92^1
N1^ST^^92^
PO1^1^4^BX^40.000^^^^^^^^IN^131470^^^1^
PID^F^^^^CATH 6FR .070 MPA 1 100CM
REF^
PO1^2^4^BX^40.000^^^^^^^^IN^131295^^^1^
PID^F^^^^CATHETER 6FR XB 3.5
REF^
PO1^3^2^EA^48.000^^^^^^^^IN^132288^^^1^
PID^F^^^^CATH 6FR AL-1 SH
REF^
PO1^4^2^BX^48.000^^^^^^^^IN^131297^^^1^
PID^F^^^^CATHETER 6FR .070 JL4SH 100CM
REF^
CTT^4^12
SE^20^00000255
GE^1^00000255
IEA^1^00000255
```

What I am trying to do is an in place edit, dropping any value in the `N1^SE` segment after the `92^`. I tried this but I cant seem to make it work:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^N1\^SE\^\^92\^\d+$/N1^SE^^92^/g' Test
```

The final result should include the `N1^SE` segment looking like this:
`N1^SE^^92^`

It worked when I just had the one line in the file: `N1^SE^^92^1`. But when I try to globally substitute in the entire file, it doesn't work

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you have no extra spaces at end of line? They do not show but will make your regex fail. See `cat -e` for example to double check.

Comment: Note that the `g` is useless. `^` will only match at the start of the string, so there can only be one match per string. (But that's fine, since you process the file one line at a time.)

Comment: The program works fine for the data you posted. Perhaps there were some hidden characters you didn't copy (such as a Carriage Return)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed to copy here some hidden character(s) or spaces. Those may well be at the end of the line so try

```
perl -i -pe 's/^N1\^SE\^\^92\^\K.*//' Test
```

The `\K` is a special form of the "[positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions)" which drops all previous matches so only `.*` after it (the rest) are removed by the substitution. <sup>†</sup>

This takes seriously the requirement "*dropping any value ... after*", as it matches lines with things other than the sole `\d` from the question's example.

Or use [\Q...\E](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters) sequence to escape special characters (see [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html))

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\QN1^SE^^92^\E\K.*//' Test
```

per [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s comment.

Another take is to specifically match `\d` as in the question

```
s/^N1\^SE\^\^92\^\K\d+//
```

per [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s comment. This stays true to your patterns and it also *doesn't* remove whatever may be hiding at the end of the line.

---

<sup>†</sup>   The term "lookbehind" for `\K` is from documentation but, while `\K` clearly "looks behind," it has marked differences from how the normal lookbehind assertions behave.

Here is a striking example from [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami).  Compare

```
perl -le'print for "abcde" =~ /(?<=\w)\w/g'  # prints lines: b c d e
```

and

```
perl -le'print for "abcde" =~ /\w\K\w/g'     # prints lines: b d
```

Comment: `s/^N1\^SE\^\^92\^\K\d+//` will do the trick without removing the hidden characters. It also won't start matching things that weren't being match before.

Comment: `\K` isn't a lookbehind. Compare `perl -le'print for "abcde" =~ /(?<=\w)\w/g'` and `perl -le'print for "abcde" =~ /\w\K\w/g'`

Comment: `s/^\QN1^SE^^92^\E\K.*//` is much easier on the eye!

Comment: @ikegami From docs I linked: "_A zero-width positive lookbehind assertion._". Perhaps it's not the best name for that functionality but I can't deviate from names in docs. Yes, matching only what they do may be better (we don't really know what's off) but they did also say "_dropping any value ... after_".

Comment: 1) Sure, you can deviate from the docs when they're wrong, but 2) the docs only say that "[`\K`] effectively provides variable-length lookbehind". It doesn't *actually* do so.

Comment: @ikegami Your second example makes a good point! (It's precisely because it drops previous matches? While for `b` and `d` there weren't any so it works there?) It means that `\K` cannot be used with `/g`; that should be documented.

Comment: It can be used with /g sometimes.  /$sep\K$pat(?=$sep)/g

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for bringing this up. I had no clue (never even thought about such differences).