# perl increment number in string with evaluation modifier

Tags: perl

I'm trying to increment:

```
Text_1_string(0)
```

to

```
Text_1_string(1)
```

and so on.
Note that I only want to increment the number in the parenthesis.
I've used:

```
name =~ s/\(([0-9]+)\)/$1 + 1/e;
```

but it turns out as:

```
Text_1_string1
```

and I don't understand why. The group captured is the number, it shouldn't replace the parenthesis.

Comment: Re "*The group captured is the number, it shouldn't replace the parenthesis.*", The *match* includes the parens, so the parens get replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It replaces the whole pattern that it matched, not only what is also captured. So you do need to put back the parens

```
$name =~ s/\(([0-9]+)\)/'('.($1 + 1).')'/e;
```

Since the replacement part is evaluated as *code* it need be normal Perl code, thus the quotes and concatenation, and parenthesis for precedence.

---

To add, there are patterns that need not be put back in the replacement part: [lookahead and lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) assertions. Like common anchors, these are *zero width assertions*, so they do not *consume* what they match -- you only "look"

```
$name =~ s/(?<=\() ([0-9]+) (?=\))/$1 + 1/xe;
```

The lookbehind can't be of variable length (like `\w+`); it takes only a fixed string pattern.

The `(?<=...)` asserts that the (fixed length) pattern in parenthesis (which do not capture!) must precede the number while `(?=...)` asserts that the pattern in its parens must follow, for the whole pattern to match.

Often very useful is the lookbehind-type construct [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions), which makes the engine keep in the string what it had matched up to that point (instead of "consuming" it); so it "drops" previous matches, much like the `(?<=...)` form

```
$name =~ s/\(\K ([0-9]+) (?=\))/$1 + 1/xe;
```

This is also more efficient. While it is also termed a "lookbehind" in documentation, there are in fact distinct differences in behavior. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51867836/4653379) and comments.  Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for a comment.

All these are *positive* lookarounds; there are also *negative* ones, asserting that given patterns *must not* be there for the whole thing to match.

A bit of an overkill in this case but a true gift in some other cases.

Comment: @susdu Welcome and no rush :).  To add, a distinct way to have patterns which are not replaced is to use "lookarounds".  For instance, `s/(?<=/() ([0-9]+) (?=\))/$1+1/xe`. Here `(?<=...)` "looks back" to see whether there is the (fixed string) pattern in parens (here a parenthesis itself, so escaped), while `(?=...)` looks ahead for the closing parens.  They aren't "consumed" so need not be replaced.